# Is the following a primitive $p$-th root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I guess I am sort of confused as to what constitutes a primitive $p$-th root of unity versus a regular $p$-th root of unity. For example if $q$ is a prime then is

$$
q^{\frac{p-1}{p}}
$$

$a$ primitive $p$-th root of unity or just a normal $pa$-th root of unity?

How can I test to see whether or not this root is primitive?  I'm working through Dummit and Foote, so if there are any specific references you can point me towards that would be great.

Comment: For a different example, $i$ (or $-i$) is a primitive $4$th root of unity, whereas $-1$ (or $1$) is a non-primitive $4$th root of unity

Comment: 3 is prime and $3^{\frac{p-1}{p}}$ is not a root of unity.

Comment: Please see:  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitiveRootofUnity.html

Comment: Please identify the ring (or group) in which you are doing this arithmetic.  The underlying notion is pretty consistent, but whether something is or is not a primitive root of unity depends on context.

Comment: $x=q^{(p-1)/p}$ is not a $p$th root of unity at all. $x^p=q^{p-1}\neq 1.$ “Unity” in “$p$th root of unity” means $1.$

Comment: It would be a primitive $p$th root of $q^{p-1}$ (although one usually wouldn't use "primitive" in this context).

Comment: I think my question was more of what @Greg Martin was suggesting, but maybe I am misinterpreting the meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up two distinct concepts, making the question not make sense.

1. A [primitive root mod $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) is a generator of the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$. It is in particular an integer.
2. A [primitive $n$th root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#General_definition) is a complex number which generates the multiplicative group of $n$th roots of unity. In particular it is a complex number of magnitude 1.